# js event not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so i finished this script that would change the image if you click on a certain image and then  reload the page. if i just put in the first part of the script so that it only works for the first image everything works properly but when i put in the second row it worn reload the page anymore and it loads the image slower. can you guys tell me what's wrong?

here is a jsfddle link http://jsfiddle.net/ex6kT/11/

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('a').one('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).delay(1000).queue(this.click).find('.1')[0].src = "images/smileys/S1.jpg";   
});
});//]]>  

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('a').one('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).delay(1000).queue(this.click).find('.2')[0].src = "images/smileys/S2.png";   
});
});//]]>  

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('a').one('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).delay(1000).queue(this.click).find('.3')[0].src = "images/smileys/S3.png";   
});
});//]]>  

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('a').one('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).delay(1000).queue(this.click).find('.4')[0].src = "images/smileys/S4.png";   
});
});//]]>  

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('a').one('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).delay(1000).queue(this.click).find('.5')[0].src = "images/smileys/S5.jpg";   
});
});//]]>  

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('a').one('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).delay(3000).queue(this.click).find('.6')[0].src = "images/smileys/S6.jpg";   
});
});//]]>  

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('a').one('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).delay(3000).queue(this.click).find('.7')[0].src = "images/smileys/S7.jpg";   
});
});//]]>  

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('a').one('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).delay(3000).queue(this.click).find('.8')[0].src = "images/smileys/S8.jpg";   
});
});//]]>  

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('a').one('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).delay(3000).queue(this.click).find('.9')[0].src = "images/smileys/S9.jpg";   
});
});//]]>  

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('a').one('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).delay(3000).queue(this.click).find('.10')[0].src = "images/smileys/S10.jpg";   
});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Comment: What's the point of this madness? Why do you have the same code for the same elements, inside the same script tags, with the same window.onload handlers, over and over again? It seems you misunderstood.... something .... exactly what is hard to tell !

Comment: you have to refactorize this code, it's really hard to understand exactly what you are trying to do. Maybe you just need to clear the queue. What about providing a jsfiddle which replicates your issue?

Comment: javascript i geuss, because i thought it would just word if i copy pasted it 10 times

Comment: Fixed your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ex6kT/13/

Comment: @adeneo: observe these lines.. `queue(this.click).find('.1')[0].src`...Though I did not understand what this code is doing but just am thinking they are different... may be. or not.

Comment: @sivatumma - they are different, but that makes it still the same, the posted code makes no logical sense whatsoever.

Comment: uhm wolff that's not what i want :S. now its just doing the same image for all the images. i want every image to have a specific image to appear when clicking it.

Comment: @user3151460 it is not what reflects your jsfiddle. Obviously, you didn't make any effort to resolve **your** issue. Logic to set specific image for each specific link clicked is not hard to get...

Comment: it is for someone who doesn't know how it works and just copy pasted this code of the internet and thought it would work if he made ten of these repeat with different targets

Answer (score 0):

You are using .one() that does the following:

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed
>   **at most once** per element per event type.

Hope this helps

Comment: In the same time, OP call click method on anchor tag which then shouldn't be an issue because of redirection

Comment: doesn't help at all i don't understand javascript. what i'm getting from your answer is that i need to change the one to ten? :P

Comment: @user3151460 no, change `one` to `on`. BTW, you should start to try to understand code you are writing...